# How to specify an element's own inner HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm very new to JavaScript so this should be a quick question, just couldn't find the answer anywhere because I didn't know what to search. 
I was wondering if it was possible to reference an element's own inner HTML. Like this:

```
<button onclick="choose(THIS BUTTON'S INNER TEXT)">Apple</button>
```

I want this button to pass the value "Apple" through to the choose() function. Can I do this somehow?

Comment: Onclick(this); then in the function call .html()

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more what you mean by call .html()? Sorry

Comment: @Doug `html()` is a jQuery thing.  The OP question doesn't have the `jQuery` tag, thus only pure JavaScript answers should be given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the inline `onclick` handler, `this` ends up referring to the element itself, so you can use any standard DOM propertly, including `this.innerHTML`.

Example below:

```js
function choose(str) {
  console.log(str);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="choose(this.innerHTML)">Apple</button>
```

Comment: Might mention that it's usually not recommended to have event listeners directly in the DOM. And you should properly use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` since OP states: `THIS BUTTON'S INNER TEXT`

Comment: @andlrc — The question also says "inner HTML" (twice)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<script>
function choose(val){
alert(val);
}
</script>

//HTML
<body>
<button onclick="choose(this.innerHTML)">Apple</button>
<body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

While the information to pass `this` in the function call is good, it's worth noting that you'd be well-served to move the JavaScript function-binding out of the HTML, to use unobtrusive JavaScript.

However, first I'll try and demonstrate that there are many means by which to retrieve the text of an element from the node itself:

```html
<button onclick="choose(this)">Apple</button>

<script>
  function choose(node) {
    node.normalize();
    var properties = {
      'innerHTML': node.innerHTML,
      'textContent': node.textContent,
      // note that node.innerText is non-standard, and
      // was defined by Microsoft, implemented in IE
      // and supplied in many browsers (see the compatibility
      // link in the references), other than Firefox:
      'innerText': node.innerText,
      'firstChildNodeValue': node.firstChild.nodeValue
    };

    Object.keys(properties).forEach(function(property) {
      console.log('node.' + property + ': ' + properties[property]);
    });
  }
</script>
```

To move away from the `onclick` in-line event-handler, to use unobtrusive JavaScript, I'd suggest using JavaScript to bind the event-handler, using `EventTarget.addEventListener()`:

```js
// here we don't pass a node into the function, we
// take advantage of the behaviour of
// EventTarget.addEventListener() to do so, within
// the function the clicked-element is passed as the
// 'this', though we cache it in a variable for
// simplicity:
function choose() {
  var node = this;

  // normalizes the child text-nodes of the element
  // joining separated adjacent text-nodes together
  node.normalize();

  var properties = {
    'innerHTML': node.innerHTML,
    'textContent': node.textContent,
    'innerText': node.innerText,
    'firstChildNodeValue': node.firstChild.nodeValue
  };

  // retrieving an array of property-keys from the
  // (above) properties Object, using Object.keys();
  // and then using Array.prototype.forEach() to
  // iterate over each of those keys:
  Object.keys(properties).forEach(function(property) {

    // property is the name of each of the Object properties/keys,
    // below we log the string of 'node.', the property itself, a
    // string of ': ' and the property-value of the property of
    // the properties Object itself to the console:
    console.log('node.' + property + ': ' + properties[property]);
  });
}


// finding the first/only (if any) <button> element using a CSS
// selector, and using EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind the
// the choose function (note there are no parentheses, if there were
// to give 'choose()' then the event-handler would be the returned
// value of the choose() function, *not* the choose function itself)
// as the event-handler of the 'click' event:
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', choose);
```

```html
<button>Apple</button>
```

Note that to use JavaScript to bind an event-handler the element whose event-handler the function is must be present in the DOM at the point at which the event-binding occurs, this can be achieved by putting the `<script>` in the document before the closing `</body>` element, or by using a DOM-ready event-listener or a `window.onload` event-handler.

References:

- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [`Node.firstChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild).
- [`Node.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText)<sup>[compatibility](http://quirksmode.org/dom/html/#t01)</sup>.
- [`Node.normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/normalize).
- [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
- [Unobtrusive JavaScript (Wikipedia article)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Answer (score -1):

This is more precise and you can get theparents elemnts id and class name ant tagname also with this.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <body>
    <!--Click the button to get id of the parent element -->

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<div id="parentDiv">
<p id="demo"></p>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("demo").parentElement.id;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
 }
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "more precise" than what? Are you responding to another answer? Your code gets the ID of an element that isn't the button and then sets the text inside yet another element to be equal to the id of some element. That seems to have almost nothing to do with the question that was asked.